# How can I classify multiple images in parallel with Inception?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, parallel-processing, tensorflow

Below is the code provided by the Tensorflow For Poets tutorial, which helps classify an image with a retrained Inception model

```
import tensorflow as tf, sys

# change this as you see fit
image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("tf_files/retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Instead of classifying only one image at a time, I'd like to classify multiple images. I know this can be done by running this process for each image by putting it's data in the `sess.run(softmax_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})` section of the code, but I would like to do this concurrently and in **parallel**.

Is there something provided by tensorflow, or maybe by Python's multiprocessing library that would allow me to make use of my multiple cores and classify my images in parallel (say maybe 4-8 at a time)?

Comment: Hm, why not to just put images in a batch?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm new to Tensorflow @DanevskyiDmytro

Comment: @DanevskyiDmytro how could I use a batch in this particular circumstance?